# Make Google maps flutter marker icon /picture rounded

Tags: flutter, maps, google-maps-markers

I have some user that have a location and a profile picture. I want to add them to a google maps flutter widget and make their picture circular. How can I do that?

This is what i tried but the markers are transparent. The api calls work normally and everything checks out , but in the end the images are transparent. I have implemented some debugging to make thing easier and everything is ok.

```
Future<Set<gm.Marker>> generateMarkers() async {
    List<gm.Marker> markers = <gm.Marker>[];

    for (final location in widget.positions) {

      String? decodedUrl = Uri.decodeFull(location.imageUrl);

      final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(
          decodedUrl.isNotEmpty ? widget.defaultImageUrl : location.imageUrl));

      if (response.statusCode != 200) {
        print(
            "Failed to fetch image. HTTP Status Code: ${response.statusCode}");
        continue;
      }

      img.Image? imageFromWeb =
          img.decodeImage(Uint8List.fromList(response.bodyBytes));

      if (imageFromWeb == null) {
        print("Failed to decode the fetched image.");
        continue;
      }

      print(
          "Image Dimensions: Width=${imageFromWeb.width}, Height=${imageFromWeb.height}");

      final int radius = imageFromWeb.width ~/ 2;
      final img.Image roundedImage =
          img.Image(width: imageFromWeb.width, height: imageFromWeb.height);

      for (int y = 0; y < imageFromWeb.height; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < imageFromWeb.width; x++) {
          if ((x - radius) * (x - radius) + (y - radius) * (y - radius) <=
              radius * radius) {
            roundedImage.setPixel(x, y, imageFromWeb.getPixel(x, y));
          } else {
            roundedImage.setPixel(x, y, img.ColorRgba8(0, 0, 0, 0));
          }
        }
      }

      print("Converted image to round shape.");

      final ui.Codec codec = await ui.instantiateImageCodec(
          Uint8List.fromList(img.encodePng(roundedImage)));
      final ui.FrameInfo frameInfo = await codec.getNextFrame();
      final ui.Image image = frameInfo.image;

      try {
        final ByteData? byteData =
            await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.rawRgba);

        if (byteData != null) {
          print("Successfully converted image to ByteData.");
          final gm.BitmapDescriptor icon = gm.BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(
              byteData.buffer.asUint8List(),
              size: Size(24, 24));

          final marker = gm.Marker(
            markerId: gm.MarkerId(location.toString()),
            position: gm.LatLng(location.coordinates!.latitude,
                location.coordinates!.longitude),
            icon: icon,
            onTap: () {
              
            },
          );

          markers.add(marker);
        } else {
          print("Failed to convert image to ByteData. ByteData is null.");
        }
      } catch (e) {
        print("Error when converting to ByteData: $e");
      }
    }

    int i = 0;
    while (i < markers.length - 1) {
      polylines.add(gm.Polyline(
        polylineId: gm.PolylineId('line[$i]'),
        points: [markers[i].position, markers[i + 1].position],
        
      ));
      i++;
    }

    return markers.toSet();
  }
```